# prevent parent element function onclick of child element

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td onclick="messageParent();">PARENT
  <div onclick="messageChild();">
  CHILD DIV
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my Javascript

```
    function messageParent(){
   alert('Parent Message');
         }

function messageChild(){
   alert('Child Message');
         }
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/zeylwinphyo/pen/EGPrRm)

When I click Parent, I call the function `messageParent()`.
When I click CHILD DIV , I call the function `messageChild()`.

But issue is , when I click `Child Div`, it also call `messsageParent()`. (two alerts show )
Can I prevent parent element's function when I click child element ??

Answer (score 4):

Call `stopPropagation` on the event to prevent the event from bubbling up to its parent. Note that you should attach event listeners using `addEventListener` in most cases - inline handlers are generally considered to be bad practice and can be difficult to manage. (with an inline handler, you could only get the event by referencing `window.event`, which is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event))

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('child');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
document.querySelector('td').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Parent Message');
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>PARENT
      <div>
        CHILD DIV
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Steven - Which you *can* do with the `onxyz`-attribute style of handler you're using as well: `<div onclick="messageChild(event);">` and then `function messageChild(event) { event.stopPropagation(); /* ... */ }` But do consider modern event handling, as shown in CertainPerformance's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the event bubbling to parents with [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
function messageParent(){
  alert('Parent Message');
}

function messageChild(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('Child Message');
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td onclick="messageParent();">PARENT
  <div onclick="messageChild(event);">
  CHILD DIV
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Code dumps aren't *useful* answers. Before posting, say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp)